# Directed graphs with non-normal adjacency or laplacian matrices

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

Is there a class of **directed graphs** whose adjacency or laplacian matrices will always be **non-normal**?

Comment: Have you found an answer to this question? It seems that non-normal are much more prevalent and people only care about normal. But even for normal, there seems still no way to say for sure.